# The python program with datetime mofule

Tags: python-3.x

I write this code in python in order to read the minute of windows clock and recognize weather it is even or odd and do it 10 times with random sleep time between 5 to 10 seconds:

```
from datetime import datetime
import random
import time
wait_time = random.randint(5,11)
time.sleep(wait_time)
for i in range(10):
    even=[2,4,6,8,10,12,14,16,18,20,22,24,26,28,30,32,
      34,36,38,40,42,44,46,48,50,52,54,56,58]
m=datetime.today().minute
if m in even:
     print("It is even")
else:
    print("It is odd")
```

But when I run it, sleep time works ok but it show the answer just one time. I think I should write the lines in other arrangement. But I don't know how to fix it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to rearrange your lines according to your own description as below. Same lines but another ordering.

```
from datetime import datetime
import random
import time
even=[2,4,6,8,10,12,14,16,18,20,22,24,26,28,30,32,
      34,36,38,40,42,44,46,48,50,52,54,56,58]
for i in range(10):
    m=datetime.today().minute
    if m in even:
        print("It is even")
    else:
        print("It is odd")
    wait_time = random.randint(5,11)
    time.sleep(wait_time)
```

Comment: I just reordered the lines but some small points: 0 (zero) is also even and should be included in the even list. Also, it is not necessary to have a list as a simple test would do the same trick: `if (m % 2) == 0: print("It is even") ...`